# Writing linked list to file truncates existing contents

Tags: c++

I am trying to read some data from a file and then put it into linked lists then add some data to it and put the data in the file again but every time I run the code it deletes the only row on the file and write new data over it.

```
struct Node
{
    string name;
    string number;
    Node* next;

};
```

**this is the function that adds to the linked list:**

```
Node *insert_down(Node* first, string x, string y) {

    Node* new_node = new Node;
    new_node->name = x;
    new_node->number = y;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (first == NULL) 
        return new_node;
    
    Node* last = first;
    while (last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = new_node;

    return first;
    

}
```

**this is the function that gets new data and add it to link list and file:**

```
void add_number(Node*first) {
    string name, number;
    cout << "enter your contact name plz : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "enter your contact number plz : ";
    cin >> number;
    first = insert_down(first, name, number);
    ofstream file("D:\\contact.txt");
    Node* temp = first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        file << temp->name << temp->number<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

**main method**

```
int main()
{

Node* contact = NULL;
string name, number;
ifstream file("D:\\contact.txt");
if (!file) {
    cout << "file can not be opend";
}

while (file >> name >>number) {

    contact = insert_down(contact, name, number);

}
file.close();

while (true) {
    menu();
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1: add_number(contact); system("CLS"); continue;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: please add an example of the data in your file

Comment: for eg I write amir for name and 9345 for number then in the file it goes like this : amir9345 but when I  want to add another data to file it remove amir9345 and write the new one over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `add_number()` method. You are just using `ofstream()` which by default opens the file in write mode, i.e with the `ios::out` flag, which truncates the file by default.

```cpp
ofstream file("D:\\contact.txt");
```

Replace it with the one below to write.

```cpp
ofstream file("D:\\contact.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

**Important:** Always read/write class objects to binary files, otherwise you might end up with serialization errors

Thus your file read will become

```cpp
ifstream file("D:\\contact.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218605/discussion-on-answer-by-debargha-roy-problem-in-writing-linked-list-to-file-in-c). If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new question.